# How to implement an indoor custom google street view

Tags: google-maps, google-street-view

I want to create an indoor google virtual tour using google street view. I've read all [Google street view documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview) specially "Providing Custom Street View Panoramas" part. but honestly I didn't get how to implement an indoor virtual tour. Let me explain the case. Suppose that I have two panorama images a and b.

image a:

[image: ![enter image description here]

1) How can I put those two white arrows in the images. and how can I set their position to point a correct position?

2) How can I link image a to b. so that when user clicks on one of the white arrow can navigate from image a to b?

3) how can I put that mouse pointer (gray arrow surrounded by a circle) to my images?

4) how can I add the cross sign on the images?

I am thankful if you give me some sample code other than those that I've seen on google street view documentation.

Answer (score 0):

1/2 are demonstrated in [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#CreatingPanoramas).

```
function getReceptionPanoramaData() {
  return {
    location: {
      pano: 'reception',  // The ID for this custom panorama.
      description: 'Google Sydney - Reception',
      latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.86684, 151.19583)
    },
    links: [{
      heading: 195,
      description: 'Exit',
      pano: outsideGoogle.location.pano
    }],
```

The `links` block creates white arrows, at specificed headings, to other panoramas (in this case, back to a default Street View one).